# add elements to the ArrayList

Tags: java, arrays, geocoding

I am trying to store the geocoordinates of the requests in ArrayList to check whether some of them are located in the same circumcircle but one element is just being added to the list after every request! How can I manage it to add all element to the ArrayList after every invoking of the request?

Receiver class:

```
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.List;

    import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
    import javax.ws.rs.POST;
    import javax.ws.rs.Path;
    import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
    import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;


@Path("/test")
public class Receiver  {

    private ArrayList<LatLong> latLongList;
    @POST
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response storeData(Data data) {

        String macD = data.getMac();
        int routeD = data.getRoute();
        float latD = data.getLatitude();
        float longD = data.getLongitude();

        latLongList = new ArrayList<>();

        latLongList.add(new LatLong(latD, longD));

        System.out.println("latLondList size: " + latLongList.size());


        Database db = new Database();
        db.insertData(macD, routeD, latD, longD);

        return Response.status(201).build();
    }
}
```

Data class:

```
@Provider
public class Data {
    private String mac;
    private int route;
    private float latitude;
    private float longitude;

  //getter setter constructor.
}
```

LatLong class:

```
public class LatLong {

    float latitude;
    float longitude;

    //getter setter constructor.
}
```

Comment: Lacking detail. I see no request!

Comment: I think you does not provide full code. Read some about application context.

Comment: @Brett: Please see my updated code I thougth this piece of code is sufficient.

Comment: Would the `latLongList` be more appropriate as a class variable?

Comment: @Brett I declares it as class variable but I am still getting the same  output `1` please see my question code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
public class Receiver  {
    private static ArrayList<LatLong> latLongList = new ArrayList<>();

    @POST
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response storeData(Data data) {

        String macD = data.getMac();
        int routeD = data.getRoute();
        float latD = data.getLatitude();
        float longD = data.getLongitude();

        latLongList.add(new LatLong(latD, longD));

        System.out.println("latLondList size: " + latLongList.size());


        Database db = new Database();
        db.insertData(macD, routeD, latD, longD);

        return Response.status(201).build();
    }
}
```

**EDIT:** Removed second `latLongList` variable.

Comment: please check your code I am gettting `Duplicate field Receiver.latLongList`

Comment: it woks if you delete the duplicate this line `private ArrayList<LatLong> latLongList;`